# Use of file with '.dat ' extension

Tags: qgis, climate

I dowloaded the climate data from this site http://catalogue.ceda.ac.uk/uuid/3f8944800cc48e1cbc29a5ee12d8542d and they have the extension .dat .
I'd like to import the information in QGIS as raster data.

Comment: What do you see if you open the .dat file with text editor?

Comment: From the menubar, go to: `Layer > Add Layer > Add Raster Layer...` and try selecting the `ZMap Plus Grid (*.dat *.DAT)` extension.

Answer (score 1):

From the **More Information** page:

> The CRU TS 3.00 data (i.e. climate variables) are available in both
>   compressed (.gz extension) ASCII ".dat" and netcdf ".nc" file formats.
>   CRU TS 3.00 metadata files (i.e. stations) are available in ASCII. To
>   understand how to read the CRU TS 3.00 data and metadata files, please
>   refer to the CRU_TS_3.00_File_Formats_explained PDF documentation
>   (under Linked Documentation below).

So you have an ASCII file - that means you can open it with a text editor or on unix do something like `head file.dat` to see what it looks like. It may well be

```
0 0 139392.2
0 1 3082792.2
....
```

Which is an XYZ file or it might be:

```
ncols         4
nrows         6
xllcorner     0.0
yllcorner     0.0
cellsize      50.0
NODATA_value  -9999
```

which is an ESRI style Ascii Grid.

QGIS can open either of these and many other variations.